# push tableview cell frame in cgrect to margin

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, frame, cgrect

In my swift code below i wan the tableview cell to be pushed to the margins exactly like the cells left side. In the photo below you can see the margins of the tableview cell on the right side are a lot bigger than it its on the side of the left. Please make them equal.

[pic of tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEnLT.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    var numberOfRows = 3
  
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { numberOfRows }

 
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 118
    }
    var btn = UIButton()
    var tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setTableVIew()
        
      
    }
    
    func setTableVIew(){

        
        let VCframe = self.view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
        let widthx = VCframe.width
        
        
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthx, height: height)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    
   lazy var backView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
    view.backgroundColor = .green
    print(self.frame.width)
        return view
    }()
    

    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
       backView.clipsToBounds = true

    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no left or right ...in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update backView frame in layoutSubviews

```
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    
   lazy var backView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
    view.backgroundColor = .green
    print(self.frame.width)
        return view
    }()
    

    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
       backView.clipsToBounds = true
       backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)

    }
```

they will become equall width cell ... if you want to give margin ... give it to your tableview instead of cell ...

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
```

Comment: I am getting a error at  backView =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110) stating Cannot assign value of type 'CGRect' to type 'UIView'